# Cannot visit installer link on red5 w. ubuntu 11.10

Tags: video, ubuntu, streaming, localhost, red5

I just installed red5 using this guide: http://labs.distriqt.com/post/493 everything works fine and if I go to localhost:5080 it shows the red5 test page. But if I click on Install a ready-made application or Launch the demo it says Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:5080. Does anybody got any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use trunk of Red5, current released version or something else.
We have set up a nightly build of red5 snapshot, so you don't need to compile the sources:
https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/Red5%20Trunk/

... and ant is also not required if you simply just want to run Red5.

Sebastian